# I have SunOS 5.10 sparc server. I want to calculate buffer memory

Tags: solaris-10

I have SunOS 5.10 sparc server. I want to calculate buffer memory. I can easily find this in Linux using /usr/bin/free command.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      8004388    7427228     577160          0     472196    3336544
-/+ buffers/cache:   3618488    4385900
Swap:     11534628          0   11534628
```

Can anyone please suggest me if there is any equivalent command in SunOS. 
It would be better if anyone can give me any Perl script to find the same in below format.

Comment: Googling gives lots of possibilities.

Comment: [Sar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sar) is available on unix & linux and can collect data continuously.

Comment: I am not able to get buffer memory wit sar. I tried all the options with sar.do you have anything specific that i can give a try?

Comment: @user95535 `sar -r`

Comment: @Xavier Lucas Sar -r print freemem and freeswap not the buffer memory. 15:04:57 freemem freeswap
15:05:02   97809  3472239
15:05:07   97711  3468778
15:05:12   97906  3475708

Comment: @user95535 Then there's no such thing on SunOS and it's reported as free memory.

Answer (score 0):

if you are root then this command

`echo ::memstat | mdb -k`

will display what you need

```
Page Summary                Pages                MB  %Tot
------------     ----------------  ----------------  ----
Kernel                    1362300             10642   17%
ZFS File Data             1705895             13327   21%
Anon                       559950              4374    7%
Exec and libs               51818               404    1%
Page cache                  17100               133    0%
Free (cachelist)            73855               576    1%
Free (freelist)           4400754             34380   54%

Total                     8171672             63841
Physical                  8154670             63708
```